# Is there a way to make a modal pop up using JS if/then statement?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to make my modal pop up when the correct boxes are checked? Right now, the modal is not popping up. Thank you! I am new to JS.

```
    document.getElementById("answer").onclick = validate;


function validate() {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("input");
    var checkboxChecked = []; 

    for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if(checkboxes[i].checked && (checkboxes[i].value === "right")) {
            checkboxChecked.push(checkboxes[i]);
        }
    }

    if(checkboxChecked.length === 2) {
        $('modal1').modal('show');
    } 
   
    else {
        alert("Wrong answer");
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe change `document.getElementsByName("input")` to `document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')`. Hard to say without a [mre].

Comment: `$('modal1')` probably needs to be `$('#modal1')` or `$('.modal1')`